# Publish model in toolbox as Geoprocessing Service?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, geoprocessing, modelbuilder

I have created a model. This models takes three shapefiles and returns the result in the form of shapefile. I run this model and found it works fine and a shapefile is created and visible in the result window and I can add it to my table of contents window.

I then publish this model as a Geo-processing service and then accessed this service. The model runs successfully as the message from the server is submitted executed and successful. There are four files created in the arcgisjobs directory of the server definition, message, result and status. These are .DAT files of which the result file is largest.

However I cannot see any shapefile created neither in the result window nor in the arcgisjobs. The only thing I can see in the result window is that name of out file with message .

I added this to my table of contents and upon looking at its properties found that it has a type of inmemory feature class, however, it does not contain any data.

What do I need to do so that the output will have some data?

I am using ArcGIS 10.0.

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution to this problem is mentioned in the online help on [**Creating models for geoprocessing services**](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#//00930000002p000000) where it says:

> Models must write their intermediate and output data to specific
>   locations